# How to pass List of Custom Objects using Dart's http?

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I am trying to pass List of Custom Object to my API.

Following is my code

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'submit_survey_question_options_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(nullable: false)
class SubmitSurveyQuestionOptionsModel {
  String questionId;
  String answer;

  SubmitSurveyQuestionOptionsModel(
      {@required this.questionId, @required this.answer});

  factory SubmitSurveyQuestionOptionsModel.fromJson(
          Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$SubmitSurveyQuestionOptionsModelFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      _$SubmitSurveyQuestionOptionsModelToJson(this);
}



Future<SubmitSurveyModel> submitSurvey(
      String userId,
      String facultyId,
      String surveyId,
      List<SubmitSurveyQuestionOptionsModel> submitSurveyQuestionOptionList,
      String subjectId) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      "userId": userId,
      "facultyId": facultyId,
      "surveyId": surveyId,
      "survey": submitSurveyQuestionOptionList,
      "subjectId": subjectId
    };

    final response = await http.post(
      SUBMIT_SURVEY_URL,
      body: json.encode(body),
    );

    SubmitSurveyModel submitSurveyModel = standardSerializers.deserializeWith(
        SubmitSurveyModel.serializer, json.decode(response.body));


    return submitSurveyModel;
  }
```

I am using `json_serializable` in my `pubspec`.
I built the serializable class using `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`

I am not able to figure out what's the problem as the data is not submitted properly?

I have referred the following links but couldn't get it working

[Flutter Error: type 'AddressInfo' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991193/flutter-error-type-addressinfo-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-string-in-type-cast)

[Dart Error Converting Object To JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753412/dart-error-converting-object-to-json)

Comment: Can you give some more detail as to what you mean by "the data is not submitted properly?" Also, what is your API expecting?

Comment: @jdixon04 the data of submitSurveyQuestionOptionList is not reflecting on the server, though it has data while submitting. I am not getting error from the server api as well.

Comment: Have you tried capturing the network request from Flutter and then submitting against your API via Postman or Insomnia? Sorry, I'd like to help but there just aren't enough details.

Comment: @jdixon04 I tried submitting via postman and it gets submitted properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the below headers

```
  Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };

  final response = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(url), body: json.encode(body), headers: headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add  **`json.encode(body)`** in body
2. Add these two header 
   **'Content-type': 'application/json',

     'Accept': 'application/json',**

   ```
    http.post(url,<br>
       body: json.encode(body),
       headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json',
         'Accept': 'application/json'},
       encoding: encoding)
       .then((http.Response response) {
   // print(response.toString());
       }
   ```